# Method override for the designated initializer of the superclass '-init' not found

Tags: ios, paypal, xcode7, braintree

I've encountered following address of Braintree in my XCode 7. Before upgrading to XCode 7, everything is working smooth. Now got that problem. Please let me know how to solve that issue.

> /.../Pods/Braintree/Braintree/API/Client/BTAPIResponseParser.m:9:17:
>   Method override for the designated initializer of the superclass
>   '-init' not found

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What version of Braintree are you using? It may be that you need to update to 3.9.3, which includes xCode7 support. (https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

You probably already know this, but just change the version number in your podfile, and then run "pod install" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After hours of struggle I got the solution:

Update the Braintree pod to 3.9.3 version

```
pod 'Braintree' , '~> 3.9.3'
```

After that in `Link Binaries with Libraries` Delete the `libPayPalMobile.a` file.

This Solution works for me.