# Braintree - bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: ios, objective-c, braintree

I have old project, when I build my project I got errors for

1. Braintree-UI-Localization
2. Braintree-Drop-In-Localization

**Error Image**

[image]

[image]

The same cocoa-pod which same version is working in its supplement project. I don't know why it is happening here.

**Already done**

Already done all answers of below links and checked project in multiple Mac's

- [Code sign error : bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)
- [bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318003/bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)
- [Xcode - Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)
- https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-ios/issues/21
- https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5742

Still not getting how to solve this errors.

**Config for project:**

- X-code 8.1
- Objective-c

Thanks.

> Edit

Update the pod as `pod 'Braintree' , '~> 3.9.3'` as per suggestion and got below errors

[image]

Comment: Are you opening the .xcodeproj file or .xcworkspace one?

Comment: .cxworkspace obviously.

Comment: It's not 'obvious' you were using correct file, hence why I asked!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem and after couple of hours of searching i found the solution.

For the solution of this error please go to following link:-
[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34673977/method-override-for-the-designated-initializer-of-the-superclass-init-not-fou/41163496#41163496)